# Topic Challenge: Non Digital Communities

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/185/78) seeking topic ideas for the challenge. Our [inaugural challenge](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/186/78) will be related to *"Non-digital Communities"*.

The goal of this topic is to build our base of questions related to communities that occur off line.

A couple examples are provided in the original suggestion for this topic.

Geographic area:

> One example of a more focused "non-digital communities" theme is questions related to your neighborhood. Any community defined primarily by geographic area or physical proximity might qualify as a neighborhood. The term typically implies a residential area but could also refer to: stores in a particular section of a shopping mall; suites in an industrial complex housing different businesses/teams; people who work near each other in an office building; etc.

Club or committee membership:

> Another example is committees, clubs, etc. These might have officers who are in charge of aspects of the organization, or they might be consensus-driven organizations where all members have the same status and privileges.

If you have a question that is part of this challenge, please added it to the answer below to facilitate tallying later. We are not going with a specific tag (or set of tags) for this challenge because this is an area that the community hasn't ventured into yet. I don't want to restrict what tags are valid for these types of questions.

This is a two week challenge as it is our first challenge, we have lower traffic so I want ensure users that don't visit daily get a chance to participate, and we have only a few suggestions and I don't want to burn through them all in a few weeks. I will tally up the results on Novemeber 29th to see how we did. We are looking for high quality questions (and answers).

If you have ideas for more challege topics, post them [here](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/185/78).

Have fun!

Comment: I just noticed the background text in the ask-a-question title field is, "What's your building, administering, managing and cultivating **digital communities** question? Be specific." (Emphasis mine.) Does that phrase come from the A51 definition? Something to make a note of for the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our first challenge has completed. We received 5 questions involving **Non Digital Communities**

- [Can't ban and the physical world has no "ignore" button; how do we deal with a disruptive member?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/874/cant-ban-and-the-physical-world-has-no-ignore-button-how-do-we-deal-with-a-d)
- [How do I help members of a community focus on work when they want to be social?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/875/how-do-i-help-members-of-a-community-focus-on-work-when-they-want-to-be-social)
- [How can I organically make sure that interested folks are included in volunteer tasks?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/879/how-can-i-organically-make-sure-that-interested-folks-are-included-in-volunteer)
- [Appropriate way to deal with a strong willed political expert](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/882/appropriate-way-to-deal-with-a-strong-willed-political-expert)
- [How to deal with a stubborn person who thinks they are perfect?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-to-deal-with-a-perfect-person)

These questions attracted 9 different answers.

Thanks to the following participants of this challenge. I feel it was very successful. Prior to this event, we had no questions dealing with community building outside of the online world.

---

[image: profile for AJ Henderson at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for Annonomus Penguin at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for Dzyann at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for James at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for Monica Cellio at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for Norm at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for Philipp at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for Zaralynda at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

[image: profile for Zerotime at Moderators Stack Exchange, Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators]

---

The next challenge will begin in the coming days. In the mean time, if you have ideas for a challenge to revolve around, or want to influence our next challenge, vote over on the [Topic Challenge suggestion thread](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185/moderators-topic-challenge)